# rcleartool fails with no permission

Tags: clearcase

I used `rcleartool` with no problem until yesterday.

In today, "write" commands fail with permission error. I do not change any configuration. I don't know whether CM server changed or not.

some examples when I encounter problem

```
cmd> rcleartool mkelem -nc {file path}
```

(some output)

```
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Can't create object with group (XXXX\Domain Users) 
that is not in the VOB's group list.
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.realException(StpExceptionImpl.java:493)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.<init>(StpExceptionImpl.java:572)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.cloneFor(StpExceptionImpl.java:956)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.cs.internal.util.StpExceptionImpl.cloneFor(StpExceptionImpl.java:980)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.WebViewBulkOpBase$ReadPropsIterWrapper.checkForBulkOpFailure(WebViewBulkOpBase.java:119)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.WebViewBulkOpBase$ReadPropsIterWrapper.next(WebViewBulkOpBase.java:81)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.WebViewBulkOpBase$ReadPropsIterWrapper.next(WebViewBulkOpBase.java:52)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.doCcVersionControl(CcFileImpl.java:280)
at com.ibm.rational.stp.client.internal.cc.CcFileImpl.doVersionControl(CcFileImpl.java:269)
at com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.MkElemCommand.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.Command.run(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.rational.ccrc.cli.command.ClearWan.main(Unknown Source)
```

(command)

```
cmd> rcleartool rmelem -f {file path}
```

(some output)

```
Request failed in method CcRpc::destroy with status 1001
(file=\nucor\server\stp\ccrpc\ccrpc.cxx, line=1751)'  
CRVAP0239E: CRVSV0078E RPC: 
CRVSV0841E 'CRVSV0613E Destroy failed: ''error detected by 
ClearCase subsystemClearCase CM Server: 
Error: No permission to perform operation "remove element".
ClearCase CM Server: Error: Must be one of: element owner, VOB owner, member of ClearCase group
```

Answer (score 1):

This is usually:

- because the current DOS session for this [`rcleartool` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&context=SSSH27&dc=D400&uid=swg24021929&loc=en_US&cs=UTF-8&lang=en&rss=ct984rational) doesn't have the right **`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`** fixed anymore
- or because of some permission issue on the parent directory where this add to source control (mkelem) takes place.

I would seriously check the first possibility, as it fits the [Primary Group requirements for element creation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21132158) and is found in other [cleartool commands like multitool](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21243039).

Note about `mkelem`:

> The `mkelem` command has different Primary Group requirements on Windows and UNIX/Linux.
>
> - UNIX/Linux:
>     In order to create an element in a VOB, your Primary Group must match a group in the VOB's group list.
> - WINDOWS:
>     As long as you "are a member of" a group in the VOB's group list and the parent directory where the element will be created is owned by the group to which you are a member, you will be able to create elements in the VOB.
>
> If, however, you are a member of more than one of the VOB's groups, the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` will need to be set to one of these.
>   See [technote 1135509](http://www-1.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21135509) for more information about the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` variable.

[user972301](https://stackoverflow.com/users/972301/user972301) refers [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301285/rcleartool-fails-with-no-permission/4301745#comment52063485_4301745) to "[Primary Group requirements for element creation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21132158)"

> I get the same error with cleartool but under Linux when I try to do an `mkelem` in a snapshot view of a child development stream whose parent is located on a different PVOB than what I usually work wit
>
> One needs to change his local machine's group ownership to match the PVOB's

Comment: I get the same error with `cleartool` but under Linux when I try to do an mkelem in a snapshot view of a child development stream whose parent is located on a different PVOB than what I usually work with -- how can this error be solved under Linux?  Is the `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable also applicable in that case?

Comment: **EDIT:** This link seems to suggest one needs to change his local machine's group ownership to match the PVOB's: [ http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21132158 ]

Comment: **RESOLVED**:  In UNIX (with `cleartool`) one must set `CLEARCASE_MKELEM_USE_GRPLIST=true` to resolve this issue.  Tested it myself in Ubuntu Linux 12.04.